# Error message when building Kotlin and Jetpack Compose desktop project: ComposeComponentRegistrar plugin not compatible

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, jetpack-compose

I am currently developing a desktop project with Kotlin, Jetpack Compose, and Gradle in IntelliJ. I am experiencing a problem during the build phase, where I receive the following error message:

```
Kotlin: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:666)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:569)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:198)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:107)
```

This is my buil.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "demo"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

These are the current settings of my gradle.properties file (I tried different settings, but without success):

```
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.0
agp.version=7.3.0
compose.version=1.3.0
```

I have attempted to use different versions of Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, but I still encounter the same error. It is important to note that the program runs correctly if compiled. I was expecting the project to build successfully without any errors.

Comment: Can you please show us the gradle.properties content? the kotlin version, agp version and compose version

Comment: I added this information to the question

Answer (score 2):

For me this error was caused by my Intellij Gradle configuration: selecting 'Gradle (Default)' for build and run in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle instead of 'Intellij IDEA' resolved the issue for me.

[image: Intellij Configuration]

I used the following 'gradle.properties':

```
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.20
agp.version=7.3.0
compose.version=1.4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I resumed the project after months of having archived it without being able to export it and I tried to make these changes but I didn't get the desired result: the error is still there. Soon I will try to resume the project and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a mismatch between the version of the Kotlin compiler and the Compose compiler plugin. To fix this error, you need to make sure that the versions of the Kotlin compiler and Compose compiler plugin are compatible.

In your case, you are using Kotlin 1.8.0, which is not a valid version. You should update the version to the latest stable version, which is currently 1.6.10.

Also, since you are using Jetpack Compose version 1.3.0, you should use the Compose compiler plugin version that is compatible with it. According to the Compose documentation, version 1.0.5 of the Compose compiler plugin is compatible with Jetpack Compose version 1.3.0.

To fix the error, you can update your gradle.properties file to the following:

```
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.6.10
agp.version=7.3.0
compose.version=1.3.0
```

Then, update your build.gradle.kts file to use version 1.0.5 of the Compose compiler plugin:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.5"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "demo"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

After updating your files, sync your Gradle project and try building again. This should resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the solution suggested didn't work. Getting an error: "Build file 'C:\Workspaces\GitHub\Personale\demo\build.gradle.kts' line: 3 - Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.compose', version: '1.0.5'] not found in sources." Also, I noticed that the latest version of the Kotlin compiler, according to the documentation, is 1.8.20.